# Why does Samsung Kies say that my device does not support software upgrading via kies?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-ace, odin, localization

I bought a Galaxy Ace. It initially came with:

1. Gingerbread 2.3.3
2. Build is GINGERBREAD.XWPKY, for regions France, Germany, Italy, Netherlands, Portugal, Spain, Turkey, UK
3. Unrooted

With that, let me add that I am from the Philippines. And I know that there's a 2.3.4 Asian ROM update (DXKPD) as per here:
http://www.pinoytechblog.com/archives/have-you-updated-your-samsung-galaxy-phones-to-gingerbread-yet

But Kies doesn't show any update. So I thought that Samsung has not released an update for that European region, and concluded that I might need to change it to my region. (Although my local carrier was able to send me GPRS settings while under this region).

So that's what I did. I used Odin on 2 attempts I did so far. I flashed it FIRST with a different region ROM (Germany, I think). SECOND time, I got it right. I now have 2.3.4 GINGERBREAD.DXKPD via Odin and using an OFFICIAL 2.3.4 Asian ROM from this page (MediaFire link):
http://rumah-android.com/new-stock-rom-android-2-3-4-s5830dxkpd-for-asia.html

Here's what troubles me.

1. Regardless if there's an update or not, Samsung Kies tells me that I couldn't update my firmware even if it's an official ROM.
2. I can't get GPRS settings now that the region's changed.

Finally, the questions:

1. Is it possible that my phone is locked to that European region? Is there such a thing?
2. Or did I use an unofficial ROM?
3. What should I do next from here?

I'm sorry this is too long. I'm confused and I just need clarifications. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it say the same BEFORE you flashed anything with Odin? and if it says there's no update and you already have 2.3.4 then simply ***there are no further updates for the  Ace based on the ROM you're using***. Phones are locked yes by the Regional carrier, most likely your carrier has ties with the European carriers hence your phone coming with an European ROM.

Comment: GPRS settings are given to you by the carrier so ask them, what you should do now? go to XDA and find another working ROM.

Comment: It said that there are no further updates for that ROM. But I wanted an update. And seeing that an official update for my region was released, I was convinced to flash it to the correct one. But I fixed it already. I found out that the CSC was set to Serbia, changed it to my country, worked like a charm. 3g signals are up, Kies doesn't show that error message and says that I have the latest firmware. But the only problem I have now is that I can't download anything from the Market. I even installed Market 3.4.4 and cleared the cache. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately there is no region-locking for phones, just carrier locking.

If your phone came with European firmware then you should probably stick with European firmware.  Ideally you'd be able to find something from your carrier even if it was re-packaged by someone for Odin.

As for your network settings, there are a couple possibilities.  You may need to supply the APN information, which you can usually find by doing a web search for "<carrier> apn" or similar.  You might also need to flash a different modem if the one you have is buggy or otherwise incompatible with your device/carrier.

Comment: Thank you, that problem is resolved now. The only trouble I have left is that I couldn't download anything from the Market after I changed the CSC. :(